# mode rewrite for m.example.com/subfolder/index.php?user=xxx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a new bee and I want to redirect following URL

m.site.com/subfolder/index.php?user=xxx

to a search engine frendly url like below using .htacess mode rewrite

m.site.com/subfolder/xxx

please explain me the correct way

Comment: This site is not a coding service. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: redirect on sub domains like this are not explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in the `.htaccess` file, in the `subfolder` (It is important):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Change R=302 for R=301 when test work well.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But now include files and css files are not conected to the website

Comment: You can use absolute URL for them, or `<base>`